# pass object stream use intent method

Tags: android

how can I pass object stream (exmple: BufferedReader or DataOutputStream n etc) to other activity **(from Client_layoutActivity.class to chat_wall.class )** if i use **intent method** like this:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Client_layoutActivity.this, chat_wall.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

I made a chat application that consists of several pages. **The first page is the login page**. in the first page, client use socket to communicated with server. **After login process is success than server will send "login success"**. **After that clien side will change layout from first page (login page) to second page (chat wall page)**. **I mean to use socket, BufferedReader and DataOuputstream method from first page (i assume  socket for login process is still connected so i can still used this socket to communicate in second page - chatting process)**. So i want to pass object Socket, BufferedReader and DataOuputstream to second page to used this. i write my code bellow:

**PAGE 1 : for login purpose**

```
public void login(){
    try {
    String name     = usrname.getText().toString(); // usrname is android object edit 
                                                       text 
    String pass     = password.getText().toString();// password is android   
                                                               object edit text 

    String sending  = "login."+name + "." + pass + "." +"\n";
     System.out.println("Sending Message: "+sending);

    Socket clientsock = new Socket("192.168.136.6", 28000);
    System.out.println("connect to the server...");

    BufferedReader in    = new BufferedReader(new  
    InputStreamReader(clientsock.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientsock.getOutputStream());

    out.writeBytes(sending);    

    String line = in.readLine();

    if (line.contentEquals("login success")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "login success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "receive data from 
    server:"+clientsock.getInetAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(Client_layoutActivity.this, chat_wall.class);
        startActivity(i); 

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println("Connection Failed");
}
```

**PAGE 2 : for Chat purpose**

```
package com.willis.layout;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import android.widget.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.R.integer;

 public class chat_wall extends Activity {

Client_layoutActivity ob;   
public EditText chatroom;    
   public Button sendbtn;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.chatwall);       

  sendbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendmsg);
  sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {                  

              sendingmsg();                                         
          }
      });

 chatroom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chatroom);     

 }   

 public void sendingmsg (){    

   try
    {   


        BufferedReader in    = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(clientsock.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientsock.getOutputStream());

    String name     = chatroom.getText().toString();            
    String send = "chat."+name+". \n";

        System.out.println("Sending message: "+send);
        out.writeBytes(send);

        String msgin = in.readLine();
        Toast.makeText(this, msgin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
    }
    }

     }
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: you can't use Intents for that.

Comment: could you please provide us with what you are trying to do with the object stream (why does it go from one activity to the next?)

Comment: @L7ColWinters: i I have written above, thanks

Comment: The socket should be in an AsyncTask and think about using handlers to recieve messages and login success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood what you want is to use the same socket for login and chat purposes. Instead of sending a `Socket` object with `Intent` between activities consider another options:

1. Define a class to manage opened sockets and create it's static instance or make it a Singleton.
2. Use a local `Service` as described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample). Define your `sendingmsg` and `login` methods in it and bind with `Activity` on it's `onResume`:

   ```
   private ChatService mService;
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       doBindService();
       sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               mService.sendingmsg();
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       doUnbindService();
   }
   ```